# Access iframe with JQuery without id

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Is there a way to access an html `iframe` without using an id. I have an iframe that is dynamically generated and gets a new id every time the page is refreshed. I am trying to dynamically resize the iframe as the browser is resized but can't seem to figure out how to access the iframe with jQuery.

Comment: There are *many*, *many* ways, but all of them depend on your specific circumstances. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ is a decent starting place.

Comment: Errrr.... can't you just give it a unique class that won't change?

Comment: Post the `iframe` (only tags), there could be a unique identifier that doesn't change.

Comment: If you want to just resize the iframe depending viewport size then you surely doesn't need js/jq for that

Comment: or just `document.getElementsByTagname("iframe")[0]` for the first iframe on the page

Comment: Answers given would work, but we can't know your specific circumstance without a sample code output.  My next suggestion would be to try an attribute selector that matches part of the given iframe URL:  iframe[href~='partofurl'], but maybe there is something else preventing that from working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over where it is generated, I'd suggest wrapping it in a parent and targeting it relative to that.

```
<div id="frameGoesHere">
    ...
    <iframe id="unknownDynamicallyGeneratedID"></iframe>
    ...
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('#frameGoesHere > iframe').function(){ /* stuff */ }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's generated by a library function and i rather not go in and try to dissect and change anything on that front.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternative selectors in a hundred different ways, this demo shows 3 ways to do it by:

- A tag selector
- A class selector
- An attribute selector

One important thing when dealing with an iframe is that it takes a longtime to load (relatively speaking of course), so place your functions within a `window.onload` or use a `setTimeout`.

[**DEMO**](https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/34596037.html)

**parent**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font: 400 16px/1.45 "Verdana";
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
            outline: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        body {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #111;
            color: #EEE;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            color: yellow;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        iframe {
            height: 210px;
            width: 600px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: white;
        }

        fieldset {
            width: 600px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        legend {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            color: yellow
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="jFrame">
        <iframe id="i-Cant" name="iName" class="iClass" src="child.html"></iframe>
    </section>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Alternate Selectors</legend>
        <label for="out1">Tag </label>
        <output id="out1"></output>
        </label>
        <label for="out2">Class </label>
        <output id="out2"></output>

        <label for="out3">Attribute </label>
        <output id="out3"></output>

    </fieldset>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            window.onload =  setTimeout(function() {

            // Selector: tag
            var targetTag = $('iframe').contents();

            // Selector: class
            var targetClass = $('.iClass').contents();

            // Selector: attribute 
            var targetAttribute = $('[name]').contents();

            var iTag = targetTag.find('article').text();
            var iClass = targetClass.find('.content').text();
            var iAttribute = targetAttribute.find("[title]").text();

            $('#out1').val(iTag);
            $('#out2').val(iClass);
            $('#out3').val(iAttribute);
        }, 3000);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Child</title>
</head>

<body>
<article  class="content"  title="Use Any Selector">This is the text that's targeted by the parent page by accessing the iframe with a tag, class, and attribute selector</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give all of the iframes a unique **id**. That way, you can select all of the iframes with `$('#uniqueId')`. If you just want to select one of them, then you can add an onClick event for each iframe, that tells you the id of itself:

```
<iframe onClick="resize('iframe1');" id="iframe1" />
```

```js
function resize(id) {
  $('#' + id).css('height', '100px'); 
}
```

Comment: Why not use a class to select by? That way you can remove the ugly and outdated `onclick` attribute and repetition of the `id`.

Comment: My problem is that the iframe is generated by a js library (epub.js). It is auto generated with it's own unique id which changes every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: If you want all of the iframes, then use `$('iframe')`.

Comment: `$('.uniqueId')` is a CLASS selector, not an ID selector (IFIFY) - also no need to pass the id of itself, just pass `onClick="resize(this);"` or for your script,  `onClick="resize(this.id);"`